# TortoiseSVN: Go back to previous revision without a working copy

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

How can use Tortoise to go back to the previous revision and make it the HEAD without a working copy?

Answer (score 0):

1. I checked-out the HEAD revision to create a local copy;
2. Exported the previous revision to another folder using the Repository Browser;
3. Copied those exported files into my checked-out folder, overwriting existing;
4. Re-added all files in my checked-out folder;
5. Committed my checked-out folder.

That seemed to work.